# How to solve the type or namespace name 'Office' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, html, outlook

I'm currently developing a system which have the send email reminder on it. I'd like to send the email through Outlook, and I'm using C# programming language and it works perfectly on my local machine but it does not work at all when I deploy it on the server, and it display the message same as the title. Can any body help me? thank you so much

```
 'protected void sendbtn_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Outlook.Application _app = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)_app.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
            mail.To = TextBox1.Text;
            mail.Subject = TextBox2.Text;
            mail.Body = TextBox3.Text;
            mail.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceNormal;
            ((Outlook._MailItem)mail).Send();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error " + ex.Message);
        }
    }'
```

Comment: This needs more info. Where /  how exactly is your C# code running? Is it a standalone app, or a library called from somewhere else? Are you using .net Core or something else?

Comment: Does the server have office installed? Outlook?

Comment: @Kjartan Hi, Thankyou for your reply. I'm using ASP.NET and in my code I add the Microsoft.Office 16.0 Object Library and Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library

Comment: @kshkarin Hi, yes I have install the office on the server.

Comment: Hi, this knowledge might be stale, but for all I know, automating Microsoft Office on a web server from a web application is unsupported, not recommended, and has various undocumented pitfalls.

Comment: if the goal is to send an email then why not use `SmtpMail` ? It works independently of Office/Outlook https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mail.smtpmail.send?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: (please! edit the code into your question, instead of attaching it as a picture)